# iPhone - Change bundle identifier

Tags: ios, nsbundle

Initially my app's bundle identifier was the default

`MyCompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`

This wasn't matching the app ID I created on the Developer Connection (a space in the product name was being turned into a hyphen) so I hard-coded the bundle identifier in MyApp-Info.plist to be

`com.MyCompany.MyApp`

However, when I log `[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]` it's still returning the old identifier. Cleaning the targets did not help. Can anyone think of where this is coming from, if not Info.plist?

Comment: Did you also check that changing in the Info.plist is automatically changing in the target?

Comment: The target references Info.plist, so I figured it would see the change. Is there another variable in the target that needs to change as well?

Comment: Is the change reflected when you click your project in the file tree, then select the summary tab.

Comment: Have you tried reseting content and settings on the sim?  Maybe then it'll set it.

Comment: I was actually using a device, but I got it to work (see answer). Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like Info.plist was cached. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730231/676001) had a great solution which updates the timestamp:

```
$ touch Info.plist
```