# Xcode5 GM crashes, "no identities are available for signing" then crash

Tags: xcode, crash, xcode5

My Xcode 5 GM crashes every time when  "no identities are available for signing" I clicked [choose].

here is crash log

```
Process:         Xcode [7923]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0 (3332.22)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3332022000000000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [143]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-09-12 02:56:10.487 +0900
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: respondsToSelector:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1412
```

and here is video.
http://youtu.be/Kwo1vq8FP-Y

Please help.

Comment: Yes I tried,but no change.

Comment: Same exact thing than in your video is happening to me with xcode 5 GM. I'm desperate, I even tried with a clean user and clean xcode and still happens, so it may be a problem in our accounts.

Comment: So make sure you have a signing identity available.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. I'm able to build/distribute Ad-hoc builds but I get the same crash at the same place when AppStore

Comment: As this is a crash in an unreleased Apple product, have you filed a bug report with Apple or otherwise contacted Apple developer support?

Comment: Thanks for comments.
For now, I have temporarily resolved by submitting using the Application Loader.

Comment: Crashes on me as well :/

Comment: This happens to me, too. I have valid signing identities in my accounts settings for both development and distribution, and I just made a new provisioning profile.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can create a new app distribution provisioning profile to fix it.
It works to me.

Comment: Same here. I was stuck with same problem. Created a new provisioning profile for distribution and it worked without issue. Go to developer portal and create new profile. I did not change or create new signing identity or cert, just provisioning profile for distribution.

Comment: This is ultimately what worked for me.  I created a new App Store distribution provisioning profile, downloaded it, and double-clicked on the downloaded `.mobileprovision` file to install it to Xcode.

Comment: Ok this works, but I thought one of the main features of Xcode 5 is to not have to go to the developer portal to create provisioning profiles.

Comment: Download and click to install :)

Comment: livesaver. By the way - if you cannot create provision profile on developer.apple.com switch to safari. It didn't worked in chrome for me.

Comment: hm, this didn't seem to work for me Xcode still tries to download new identities even though I've added the profile.

Answer (score 6):

On a brand new project, with a brand new Xcode 5, with a brand new developer account, with freshly created certificates, app ID, and distribution provisioning profile, I the exact same problem.

**Compare your Provisioning Profile's Bundle Identifier with what is on your project's info tab!**

I had created my app ID (as I always do) using all lowercase letters.

When Xcode creates a new project, the template has Bundle identifier set to com.company.${PRODUCT_NAME} which resulted in a capitalized product name.  This will also result in the same problem.

This.  This right here is that lighting bolt of pain right above your eye.  Like an ice pick.

Comment: You. YOU SAVED ME!!!! Thanks Mike for this comment. I was about about to waste a lot more time on this.

Comment: Glad to know.  I wasted 2 days on this, myself.

Comment: How do I fix it? my bundle identifier is actually com.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} while the info tab it says: com.Mycompany (capital M) but how can I see the provisioning profile bundle identifier?

Comment: You can change the field to be com.mycompany.appname or whatever your bundle identifier is from the developer portal.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried 30 other remedies and this worked. My bundle ID didn't match. Man app store distro is a beast!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue to fix this for me I did not have a valid Distribution Provisioning Profile attached to the build. Hope this fixes the problem for you.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

I used the [shenzhen](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen) gem and Application Loader.

**Step 1**

Be sure to have all your profiles and certificates imported in Xcode, and set properly at *target* level.

**Step 2**

Generate the ipa. *This I couldn't do with Xcode, because it keeps crashing.*

> ipa build -c Release

*Don't forget to use the Release configuration*.

**Step 3**

Upload the generated `.ipa` with Application Loader.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!