# Delete Provisioning profile from Titanium Studio

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, provisioning-profile, appcelerator-mobile

I have more that 10 provisioning profiles in Titanium studio. Whenever I add single device in my developer apple account I have to generate new provisioning profile and download it on my mac. And then choose new profile from 'Titanium'-> 'Run'-'Run Configuration'-> 'Titanium IOS Devices' and this have drop down of all the profiles. 
How can I delete old profiles from here as there is no way to sort these profiles by date so I have to memorize all profiles before downloading new profile and then by comparison find out which is newly add to select for build.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: for deleting provisioning profile you have to use Xcode

Comment: complete Steps please.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think that you can do it using Titanium Studio ,but there are some other options.

[Delete provisioning profile from Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923095/delete-provisioning-profile-from-xcode-5)

[How remove a old provisioning profile in xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530712/how-remove-a-old-provisioning-profile-in-xcode-5)

[removing provisioning profile from xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922695/removing-provisioning-profile-from-xcode)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

Then just go in Titanium Studio to "Run Configurations" -> "Titanium iOS Device" -> "Manage Settings" (Below SDK version) and refresh the list with prov. profiles.