# iOS - cannot validate my app "No identities are available for signing"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing

Xcode doesn’t find signing identities. Always appears “No identities are available for signing”.
I add iOS Distribution certificate. Ad hoc provisioning profile appear in the Provisioning Profile pop-up menu

1) I created an iTunes Connect app record.
2) Registered all test devices.
3) Created a distribution certificate.
4) Created an ad hoc provisioning profile.
5) Updated the built string.
6) Archived app

When i tried to validate app appeared dialog “No identities are available for signing”

I checked in Xcode->Preferences->Account->View Details that i have iOS Distribution certificate and Ad hoc provisioning profile. They are appeared in pop-up menu.

I checked Bundel ID in XCode match Bundle ID in iTunes Connect. They matched.

When i tried again to validate app appeared dialog “No identities are available for signing”

I tried do everything from this question: [No identities are available for signing Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746703/no-identities-are-available-for-signing-xcode-5)

But still get this error(

Comment: You say  Bundel ID in XCode match Bundle ID in iTunes Connect but does it match the certificate's id? for example com.google.* for certificate will allow you to sign anything for com.google.YourApp, but a certificate for com.google.myApp won't sign YourApp.
Also, did you restart xCode since you loaded the certificate?

Comment: Are you sure you are archiving using the Ad-hoc build configuration? Check your scheme.

Comment: @Pierre-FrancoysBrousseau In Xcode->target->general my Bundle id com.mycompany.projectname, in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles I have Identifiers with id com.mycompany.projectname. I tried to restart Xcode, it doesn't help. I check Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme-> Archive-> Build Configuration: Release

Comment: @JackWu  In Xcode->target->Build Settings-> Code Signing->Provisioning Profile->Release i saw my AdHoc profile

Comment: @helecta Thats not what I was referring to, go to "Edit Scheme" in the top left of XCode where you choose the target device. Make sure that release is point to Ad-Hoc