# Code signing broken on Xcode 5.1 + iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode

Seems Apple has broken provisioning profiles in Xcode 5.1 ??

1. Upgraded to Xcode 5.1
2. Plugged in a device that wasn't registered on Dev Center
3. Asked Xcode to auto-add it

Result:

1. Developer Provisioning Profile is now corrupt in Xcode5

The following had no effect:

1. Restarting Xcode
2. Deleting profile and re-downloading within Xcode
3. Check that certificate is valid
4. Re-building with other profiles for same account/project (i.e. Distribution profiles) that had NOT been changed (works fine)

NOTE: in iPhone Configuration Utility, the profiles shows up as valid with all the registered devices. In Xcode5.1 I get:

> Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning
>   identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the
>   provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“iOS Team
>   Provisioning Profile: com.irisconnect.betairisconnect”) were found.

Comment: I got the same error message after klicking the "update" button in the account settings in XCode 5.1 for the first time. Luckily i could solve it by restarting Xcode. My profiles in keychain looked good all the time. Probably some nasty XCode bug...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution: it's Xcode 5.1 that is broken, with a major bug.

If you allow Xcode5 to download provisioning profiles, it now internally corrupts any Developer profiles it downloaded.

If you instead:

1. quit Xcode
2. login to web version of Dev Center
3. manually download the profile
4. install using iPhone Configuration Utility
5. Re-start Xcode

...everything works fine.

Note: if you *ever* do the download within Xcode 5.1, then no amount of restarts will help you :(.

Thanks, Apple.

Comment: Meaning that if someone started developing on 5.1 that person doesn't have any chance to have an ipa of his project? Could you give a link to the bug description?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie If you want a link, you'll need to phone up Apple and ask them to start publishing their bugs (they don't; all bugs - both "known" and "fixed" - are state-secrets as far as Apple is concerned. Some "fixed" bugs get added to release-notes - but only a few! AFAICT there's no actual benefit to this, just makes life hard for all developers)

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie If you get this problem, use iPCU to delete your profiles and re-downlad as instrcuted above.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem and was tearing my hair out.  thanks to the answer above, i went and looked in keychain access and saw that my previous iPhone Developer certificates were listed as expired. so, i deleted these in keychain access.

then:

1) i went to the apple developer portal (https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action?type=development), clicked on the development certificate, and clicked download.
2) i dragged that certificate into keychain access (it's a login cert).
3) i went back to xcode, to the build settings code signing section of the project.
4) by hand, i set the provisioning profiles to my team provisioning profile.
5) i went up into the code signing identity section and by hand selected the new code signing identity.

and voila, it worked...my project built.
btw, i went through all that because i had made the fatal error the prior answer indicated, i.e. i had let xcode download a new certificate and then let it try to fix the code signing issue, and got caught in 1 infinite loop...just kept failing...

hope this helps

Comment: ps. i forgot to mention that in addition to the expired certs that i deleted, there was also a new, unexpired cert that i believe xcode had downloaded...that one had no provisioning profiles associated with it and didn't work for the code signing, which is probably why, as adam said, doing the download within xcode may have caused the problem...i had to select the cert i downloaded by hand and dragged into keychain access, and that had my team provisioning profile associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.

Here is my solution

1. Download Provision from https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action?type=production
2. You will get the file name "mobileprovision", change it to "YourAppName.mobileprovision"
3. Now Click open it with xCode
4. Archive and Submit your application again by Organizer

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me on Xcode 6, iOS 8.

1. Visit https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action?type=production
2. Revoked all certificates
3. Closed/restarted XCode.
4. Attempted to Build/Run again.

This time the Auto Fix process in XCode worked.