# xcode identity not working

Tags: ios, xcode

I saw this page: [No identities are available for signing Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746703/no-identities-are-available-for-signing-xcode-5)

I created an identity and I downloaded it. It can't be imported to xcode in the organiser-archives page. When I try to import it, it is greyed out. When I double click the profile, it opens up to the devices page in the organiser window but does nothing. When I click download identities from developer center it refreshes the "No identities are available" pages and does nothing. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Restart Xcode and do a Clean. Also cross check the certificate that you have created( Distribution / Ad-hoc)

Comment: Really?  What have certificates etc. got to do with a project build?

Comment: most of the time, a restart & clean will fix this issue in Xcode5.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Xcode-> Preferences-> Accounts-> View Details, Refresh the Window. The Added profiles from Developer portal will get reflect on Xcode.

[image]

Comment: tried that doesn't work for me, i tried clean like 1 million times but still no