# Force Xcode to update project files

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

**OK, here's my issue :**

- I'm using Xcode 4.6 under Lion
- In my current project I've added several "real" folders (either with sources or with resources) which Xcode represents as **"Groups"**
- However, whenever I add another file in one of my already-imported folders, the file doesn't show up *(but instead I have to manually drag each new file to its appropriate location)*.

Well, given that my project is comprised of hundreds of different files, and that files are being added constantly, this seems like an overkill.

I realize this may have to do with Xcode's Group-centric approach, but it still bothers me.

So, is there any workaround? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for many IDE, it won't scan changes of new files in included folder, to prevent accidental add of extra codes that will break the compile process. If you really want to do so, write a script to add all files in the folder and run it at pre-compile stage, i.e. in Xcode, "External Target"

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/976459/188331