# Xcode check for license header

Tags: xcode, scripting, comments, licensing

I'm not even sure this is possible, but I'll give it a shot.

Is it somehow possible (i.e. with a plugin) for Xcode to check if every File contains a valid license header, and if not stops compiling?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete Setup! Note that this will produce Xcode erros too. :)

```
#!/bin/bash

searchString=`cat license.txt`

ERROR_COUNT=0
while read file
do
    grep -F "${searchString}" $file > /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo -e $file:1: error : No valid License Header found! 1>&2 
        ERROR_COUNT=1
    fi
done < <(find . -type d \( -name "TTTAttributedLabel" -o -name "minizip" -o -name "SSZipArchive" \) -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.m" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.pch" \) -print)


exit $ERROR_COUNT
```

And here is how to setup the Script:
[Xcode: Running a script before every build that modifies source code directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976454/xcode-running-a-script-before-every-build-that-modifies-source-code-directly)

How to report Errors in Xcode:
http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2010/12/04/xcode-shell-build-phase-reporting-of-errors/

Answer (score 1):

Well im not sure if this is the correct answer, but you could add a shell script to your build phase which could check the files in your project for the valid license header (via grep+regex).

Comment: Thanks I didn't know this was possible. I'll post back once I've got everything up and running.