# Xcode doesn't pick up files changed by pre-action script

Tags: swift, xcode, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager, xcode-project

In my project I need to generate a file that will be used in one of my Swift Packages.

I added a script to generate it as a `pre-action` to make sure it happens before anything else is build - and it works.

File is generated properly - it appears in Xcode project itself.
But Xcode doesn't pick it up when compiling this Package for the first time.
Next time I compile it - it catches it properly, but all further changes are not picked up again on first time it gets modified...

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976454/xcode-running-a-script-before-every-build-that-modifies-source-code-directly) with similar issue, but none of the solution works for me.
Doing it as a Step in Build Phases doesn't solve the problem, making it even worse.

Is there any reasonable solution to run some code generate that will be properly picked up by Xcode ?